# Long running process on Heroku (Nodejs and Puppeteer)

Tags: node.js, heroku, puppeteer

So I have this Node app where I'm calling a function that, using Puppeteer, does basically this:

- goes to a website, gets a table and grabs some items from the table.
- for every one of these items, it will go to another website, do a search based on that item and then return a specific value for me.

These table items can be hundreds, so it will basically visit the second website hundreds of times. This is the base code for all of this:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  timeout: 0,
  args: [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--disable-dev-shm-usage'
  ]
})
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0)
await page.goto(url1, { timeout: 0 })

const items = await page.evaluate(selector => {
  const tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
  return tds.map(td => td.innerText)
},'#table')

await page.close()

const res = []

await Promise.all(
  items.map(async item => {
    try {
      const analyserPage = await browser.newPage()
      const pendingXHR = new PendingXHR(analyserPage)
      await analyserPage.goto(url2, { timeout: 0 })
      await analyserPage.type('input#input', item)
      await analyserPage.click('button#submit')
      await pendingXHR.waitForAllXhrFinished()

      const result = await analyserPage.$eval(
        '#results',
        el => el.innerText
      )

      if (result) {
        res.push({ item, result })
      }

      await analyserPage.close()
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
)

return {
  res: res.sort((a, b) => b.result - a.result)
}
```

So this is working totally fine locally, even though it may take quite some time. When deployed to Heroku, this simply doesn't return anything and I don't see anything on the errors logs as well.

Is something like this simply impossible on Heroku's free tier? Can I do something to at least be able to debug it?

Comment: "and I don't see anything on the errors logs as well"—well you don't appear to be doing very much logging. Maybe start by adding some.

Comment: So you're not seeing any [H12 errors for exceeding the 30-second request window](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#http-timeouts)? About how long does this job take? Seems like a good fit for a worker process.

Comment: @Chris regarding stuff like Heroku memory or timeout errors, which I was seeing in the past due to some other problems, but now I don't see them anymore. How exactly should I add error logging here?

Comment: @ggorlen nope, I was seeing that before on a previous iteration of this code, but now not a single one in sight. So I should try to use a service worker here to handle these heavier tasks?

Comment: @EduardoJoão, add logging wherever you think it makes sense. And you don't just have to log _errors_, you can log informational stuff, too. Log a message when the page loads and include some basic information about what it contains. Log what your query selector matches. Log a message every 10 or 100 or 1000 items in your loop. At the moment we have no idea what is happening. We need to get some visibility.